# Binding actions with hardrive links

Tags: jquery

I encounter a problem with jQuery and anchors which href concerns a microsoft desktop windows application.
I am working on an internal app which provides links such as :

```
<a id="launch-21" class="launch-app" href="c:\windows\explorer.exe" target="_blank">
```

I would like to target all the link containing windows for instance in order to bind the following actions :

```
jQuery('a[href*="windows"]').click(function(event){
    alert("use this link in your windows workstation");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This has no absolutly no effect.
But when I run the following selector, elements are well returned.

It seems the treatment doesn't work with hard drive links ?
jQuery('a[href*="windows"]')
Does anybody an help me ?

Comment: When you say "no effect", do you mean that nothing happens?

Are these links static or dynamic? When does the event binding happen in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work without any problem,

Maybe you're running it before `$(document).ready` is triggered, or the links in question are loaded in the DOM and ready to be parsed using javascript.

Try changing your javascript to:

([I've created a fiddle for this, you may test it there](http://jsfiddle.net/fYAXL/))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[href*="windows"]').click(function(event){
        var link = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        window.prompt("use this link in your windows workstation", link);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

*(please note that i took the liberty of changing your alert to a prompt in order to do some testing)*

In alternative you can also move your javascript to the end of the page, before closing your `<body>` tag.